# kubernetesの構築方法

Tags: kubernetes

クラウド上でkubernetesによるインフラ構築を検討しています。

コンテナを3層に分け、パブリックセグメント、プライベートセグメントによるネットワークを作成した上で、webコンテナをパブリックセグメントに、アプリケーションおよびデータベースコンテナをプライベートセグメントに配置しようと検討しています。

そのような場合に、構成として、
①2つのk8sによるクラスタをそれぞれパブリックセグメントとプライベートセグメントに分け、各クラスタ内でノードを作成し、クラスタを跨いで通信させるケース
②１つのk8sによるクラスタにパブリックセグメント、プライベートセグメントを含ませ、ノードをパブリックセグメント、プライベートセグメントに分けて構築し、クラスタ内で通信させるケース
③1つのk8sによるクラスタをプライベートセグメントのみでノードを構築し、Webコンテナを外部のロードバランサを使用するサービスtypeで、全てプライベートセグメント内で通信するケース
の３パターンを考えています。

構築の容易さ、セキュリティの高さを考慮した場合、どのケースが最も良いケースとなるのでしょうか。
また、①の場合、service名で通信できないため、どのようにクラスタ間通信すればよいのでしょうか。